# Can I boot Ubuntu from external drive if Windows is hibernated?

Tags: boot, system-installation, hard-drive, hibernate

I have a laptop running Windows 10 on a 1TB HDD.
I want to install Ubuntu on a 64GB sd card. But first, I would like to know if it's safe to keep Windows **hibernated** on the HDD. Will Ubuntu corrupt the Windows `hiberfil.sys` hibernation file (or any other important files stored on the HDD), if Ubuntu is running from the sd card, during the installation and/or after the installation?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Linux live system will not change anything on the PCs hard disk (unless you tell it to).

I do it frequently to use a company laptop for private purpose.

Only thing is that some windows drivers on DELL Laptops have problems when Linux was booted in between. The display might  flicker a little afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't understand if the "yes" was referring to "Is it safe to keep Windows hibernated on the HDD?" or to "Will Ubuntu corrupt the Windows hiberfil.sys hibernation file...?".

Comment: Sorry, I received your question as a *yes/no* type, but the real *yes/no* part in your question has to be answered with **no**. I update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run Ubuntu whilst Windows is hibernated however you will not be able to access any of the Windows data files.

`Nautilus`, the Ubuntu file manager, will tell you Windows is hibernated whenever you try to access the drive.